# Why when parameter is null, postgres throws an exception?

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, shopizer

```sql
@Query(value = "select distinct m from MerchantStore m 
left join fetch m.parent mp left join fetch m.country mc 
left join fetch m.currency mc left join fetch m.zone mz 
left join fetch m.defaultLanguage md 
left join fetch m.languages mls where (?1 is null or m.storename like %?1%)",
countQuery = "select count(distinct m) from MerchantStore m where (?1 is null or m.storename like %?1%)")
    
Page<MerchantStore> listAll(String storeName, Pageable pageable);
```

I have the query from above, but it throws the following exception:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying ~~ bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

When I rotate the condition to `(m.storename like %?1% or ?1 is null)` then it works okay.

Could someone explain to me what is going on here exactly?
P.S. this is from Shopizer library, PageableMerchantRepository.java.

Comment: what's the sense of `?1 is null`? like if `storeName = "StarBucks"` you will have  `"starbucks" is null`

Comment: What query is actually getting sent to the database?

Comment: In which query are you rotating the conditions? And should that not be `m.storename is null`?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia it is a common (if unfortunate) short cut taken by programmers who don't want to dynamically assemble their queries.  "If I provide a NULL parameter then this expression is always true" is a way to ignore the other branch of the expression, without having to remove it from the query.

Comment: @jjanes so how do I fix it? What would be the correct way to do it? This isn't my code and I haven't used Query before. It's like this in every single query they wrote and none of them works when I set up the db.

Comment: The problem seems to be with 'shopizer', something I've never even heard of before.  If we could at least see the query as sent to the database we could speculate intelligently, but the only way for us to see it is if you show it to us.

Comment: @jjanes hmm, I can paste what I have from the application log, but it doesn't show the parameters just shows ?1 , I'll look into how I can get the query with the parameters.

Comment: @jjanes so parameter seems to be null, here is how it looks in the log once I rotate the conditions: https://pastebin.com/BuDNprbj

Answer (score 0):

It could be because [`MerchantStore.storename`](https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer/blob/36fe2a5b0a20d6bbd45d8719bfe8afe22f0bd5dc/sm-core-model/src/main/java/com/salesmanager/core/model/merchant/MerchantStore.java#L89) is a non-nullable field/column! ;)

```
(?1 is null or m.storename like %?1%)
```

which postgres obviously not seems to like (with my words: "null is no valid 'data type' for that column"), whereas in:

```
(m.storename like %?1% or ?1 is null)
```

`?1 is null` (obviously!?) never evaluated.

So do it:

```
m.storename like %?1%
```

, and ensure to pass no nulls/what to do with them (`like %null%` or `like '%'`?).